# What the valid value range for getTimezoneOffset()?

Tags: javascript, timezone-offset

My client's browse return timezone offset value is 1020. Is it valid? If it's valid what Etc/GMT zone it is? Thanks a lot.

Comment: From [the MDN page for getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset): `The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time.`  Note: this is minutes, not hours.

Answer (score 0):

If it is +1020, that would be -17 in UTC (priorly known as GMT, as alluded to in Collective Cognition's comment), but that appears to be invalid: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone

Comment: To clarify a little, getTimezoneOffset returns the difference between UTC and local time in minutes. 1020 minutes / 60 is 17 hours as per Brett's answer.

Comment: In which situation it can return invalid value? Any suggestions to deal with invalid value? I need to change server time to client's local time. Seems I have no way to accomplish it if browser return invalid value.

Comment: No idea. Maybe you could post a message (or send an email if the user has allowed it) that the user's browser is not configured for an optimum experience. Otherwise, I think you could only go at its face value and actually shift the time in that manner. I see someone reported an issue at http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-is-set-to-utc-17 . Are you on Wordpress?

Comment: Thanks, I am not on Wordpress.